# Firewall - proxy setting for connecting HazelCast server host:port

Tags: hazelcast

Is there way to set  Proxy settings (route via proxy Server)  for HazelcastClient to connect to remote cache server (which is behind a firwall)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No since Hazelcast clients use an internally developed (even though open source), plain TCP protocol, there is no real proxy support. You might be able to use a SOCKS proxy though but this is not supported.

There's also a prototype to tunnel the protocol through a HTTPS session but same thing, not officially supported: https://github.com/noctarius/https-tunnel-openshift-hazelcast